# Sore loser or bad loser

Tags: word-usage

I can't find the if these two expressions have the same meaning. I would like to know if "sore loser" and "bad loser" have the same meaning.

---

<sub>*Note: Originally asked about "sore player" or "bad player".*</sub>

Comment: Did you mean 'sore loser' and 'bad loser'?

Comment: Never heard 'sore player', but 'sore loser' is commonplace.

Comment: Americans are more likely to say "sore loser" and Brits to say "bad loser", both mean the same thing.

Comment: Oh yes I meant sore loser. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I went ahead and edited your post based on your comment. I assume you also meant "bad loser" (_sore loser and bad loser_). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 1):

We do not usually call people taking part in games, competitions, sporting or other wise, "bad" or "sore" **players**, but we can call someone who behaves childishly, badly or unsportingly, after losing in a game, competition, etc, a bad or sore **loser**. "Bad" is more common in British English, and "sore" is more common in American English.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your help.